# SQLite Net Extensions OneToMany relationship not inserting/saving/updating Children

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm attempting to use SQLite Net Extensions to do a note taking app for games, it uses 3 layers of models, `Game [1 has many *] Character [1 has many *] Note [1 applies to *] Character`

I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio Community 2015 and installed SQLiteNetExtensions using the NuGet package manager.

I'm not past the first level of relationships between Game and character yet, and Inserting into the database (whether via initial insert and then update, or using InsertWithChildren recursively) is not updating the Characters in the Game object. It just results in a null object for the `List<CharacterModel>` inside GameModel. However both the game and the characters are making it on the database.

Abstract base model

```
public abstract class IdentifiableModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Game Model

```
[Table("Game")]
public class GameModel : IdentifiableModel
{
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<CharacterModel> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

Character Model

```
[Table("Characters")]
public class CharacterModel : IdentifiableModel
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof (GameModel))]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public GameModel Game { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

To test inserting into the database I do this on my Main activity:

```
var game =
    new GameModel
    {
        Name = "Game"
    };

database.Insert(game);

var characters = new List<CharacterModel>
{
    new CharacterModel
    {
        FullName = "Dude"
    },
    new CharacterModel
    {
        FullName = "Dudette"
    }
};

database.InsertAll(characters);

game.Characters = characters;

database.UpdateWithChildren(game);

var testGame = database.GetAll<GameModel>().FirstOrDefault();
var testCharacter = database.GetAll<CharacterModel>().FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(testGame.Id + " " + testGame.Name);
Console.WriteLine(testCharacter.Id + " " + testCharacter.FullName + " " + testCharacter.GameId);
//testGame.Characters;  // THIS IS NULL.
//testCharacter.Game;  // THIS IS NULL.
```

I'm at a loss at where to begin sorting this and would appreciate some help getting it up and running.

---

*Edit:* Using a non-inherited Primary Key made no difference at all. Still no data in `testGame.Characters` or `testCharacter.Game`

Comment: As part of the Abstract base model, all primary keys are the property ```Id``` in the extended class.

Comment: I am not sure about if inheriting the PK works or not. I also doubt that it has a value.

Comment: I'll see if it works without it, the Xamarin tutorial uses inherited PK though:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/

Comment: @NoChance - it made no difference, I've update the question.

Comment: Thx. for the update.

Comment: I see that you insert characters, but where is the parent 'game' for them? How would the game PK value be used without referencing the Game?

Comment: I simply reference the game using the same object to make sure I'm pulling the correct game, PK references would be held by the front end later for use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite-Net Extensions extends SQLite.Net with additional methods that loads and writes relationships. You are writing the relationship to database using `UpdateWithChildren` method, but you are not loading the relationship from database because `GetAll` is a plain SQLite.Net method.

Try using any `*WithChildren` variant of SQLite.Net methods, for example:

```
var testGame = database.GetAllWithChildren<GameModel>().FirstOrDefault();
```

or:

```
var testGame = database.GetWithChildren<GameModel>(game.Id);
```

Alternatively you can load relationships of already existing objects calling `GetChildren` method:

```
var testGame = database.GetAll<GameModel>().FirstOrDefault();
testGame.GetChildren();
```

Comment: Spot on. It's now working. I had a little issue after switching the methods with this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32622 the solutions there worked and cleared up the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem due to missing CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All. Add the instruction as below resolve my issue

```
[OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
```

Comment: Amazing, I've been struggling with this all day, and I had mine set to "CascadeOperation.Delete" which was useless until I changed to "All". Thank you.